# Few field of INPUT form not allowing to enter Data

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form, there is a button (+sign)on the form which appends a row to insert the value .In my form i am able to enter the value on the first row both fields( `stationerytype` and `stationeryqty`). But once I append  a new row by clicking plus button I am not able to insert any value  on `staionerytype` field of second row while I'm able to insert the value in the `stationeryqty` field of second row.

My code is:

```
<table   class="table table-bordered" id="tb" >
<tr class="tr-header">

<th class= "col-md-1" align="centre">Sl.No.</th>
<th class= "col-md-6" align="centre">STATIONARY TYPE</th>
<th class= "col-md-4" align="centre">STATIONARY QUANTITY</th>
<th class= "col-md-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Stationery"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>

</tr>
<tr>
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=1;$i++)
{   
?>

<td><input type="text" style="text-decoration: none" name="slno" value= "<?php echo $i; ?>"  ></td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-decoration: none" name="stationerytype"  ></td>
<td><input type="number" name="stationeryqtyrecd" id="stationeryqtyrecd" min="0"></td>

<td><a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
</tr>
<?php  }?>
</table>

<button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-info"  align="middle" >ADD </button>   

<script>
var max = 4;
var count = 1;
$(function(){
    $('#addMore').on('click', function() {
            if(count <= max ){
              var data = $("#tb tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
              data.find("input").val('');
              debugger;
              data.find("input")[0].value=++count;
            }else{
             alert("Sorry!! Can't add more than five samples at a time !!");
           }
              
     });
     $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
         var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if(trIndex>1) {
             $(this).closest("tr").remove();
           } else {
             alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");

     var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        if(trIndex>1) {
         $(this).closest("tr").remove();
         count--;
         
         // get all the rows in table except header.
         $('#tb tr:not(.tr-header)').each(function(){
         $(this).find('td:first-child input').val(this.rowIndex);
         })
           }
      });
}); 
 
</script>
                            </div>
```

Comment: This looks like a JS question, not PHP. Please make sure you only add tags that are relevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: This is debatable as you do use a php loop to write out the initial elements, that said I agree with Magnus, the actual issue isnt really related to php so the tag really isnt a good fit

Comment: As for the actual issue, are you sure there's not something else causing this problem. I've recreated your circumstances here https://jsfiddle.net/e6gvy5sb/. I did have to fix several syntax issues that I assume are not present in your actual code but it appears to work as expected.

Comment: Also worth noting, the `id="stationeryqtyrecd"` in your php loop will produce invalid html as ids are required to be unique, you might want something like `id="stationeryqtyrecd<?php echo $i; ?>"`